# How to display Cloudinary assets (integrated from Contentful) with Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, cloudinary, contentful, contentful-management

I have been recently exploring Contentful CMS and I have been trying to display Cloudinary images/videos that I already placed in Contentful Content Model (JSON field with Cloudinary app applied) into Next.js 13 (I'm using their starter guide: https://www.contentful.com/nextjs-starter-guide/), but I'm pretty new to this so I get stuck lots of times. I have tried to watch their video on how to integrate Cloudinary from Contentful and Next.js but I get confused on how and where they got their GraphQL queries.
[image]

My code is basically the same with their example here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-contentful. Its just a matter on how to connect a content JSON to display the Cloudinary app I installed in Contentful. I don't see lots of examples to display Cloudinary assets to Next.js, unless you can tell me otherwise...

If you have any resources or advice you can point me too, I would be happy to hear them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the data from the Cloudinary app, you will have to modify the GraphQL query. In my example, I added the Cloudinary app and connected it with the Cloudinary App JSON field as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of the Post content type]

Now, to fetch the data from that field, I just had to add `cloudinaryApp` in my GraphQL query. So now my query looks like:

```
const POST_GRAPHQL_FIELDS = `
slug
title
cloudinaryApp
date
author {
  name
  picture {
    url
  }
}
excerpt
content {
  json
  links {
    assets {
      block {
        sys {
          id
        }
        url
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

I hope this helps :)